# Twilio: can't get Studio Flow to respond to message

Tags: python, widget, twilio, sms, twilio-flow

I'm trying to get my Flow to respond to the following

```
def flow_twilio(first_name,repeats_left):
    # Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    # and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    account_sid = 'AC7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
    auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    execution = client.studio \
                  .v1 \
                  .flows('FW8057d9d1f84b19286bd466253ab86cad') \
                  .executions \
                  .create(parameters={
                     'f_name' : first_name, 'rpts': repeats_left, 
                   }, from_='+12763888591', to='+353876201920') 
    print(execution.sid)
```

Here's my Studio Flow:
The confirm_repeat widget is not doing anything, is there something obvious I'm not seeing. I've looked at the logs and can't figure out whats wrong with it.
Any input or advice greatly appreciated, tks, Ian
[image: Studio Flow]

Here's the log from the Flow
[image]

Comment: I just changed trigger from incoming message to REST API but sill no response

Comment: Do you see that anything happens in the logs, i.e. is the flow listed?

Comment: I've added a shot of the log above, the flow looks active but seems to timeout after an hour

Comment: Could you try with v2 of the REST API? client.studio.v2
Also, did you double-check that the FLOW SID is the same one you're using?

Comment: And can you explain the log of he "send and wait for reply" widget to show what happened there.

Comment: I logged it with Twilio, the guy got back to me and explained that my Twilio number is US and I'm sending SMS to Ireland. He suggested I buy an Irish number so I'm going to give that a try

Comment: Oh yea he also suggested I switch to V2 so thanks for spotting that. Cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you were able to figure it out, that's great! I'll leave this answer here for others who might come along this issue.

Check which international long codes you’re using to send messages to Ireland in Twilio Console. Refer to our [How Can I Check If I Am Using International Senders to Send Traffic To A Specific Destination?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/14834351575579-How-Can-I-Check-If-I-Am-Using-International-Senders-to-Send-Traffic-To-A-Specific-Destination-) guide and follow the steps below:

Log into Twilio Console and select Messaging Insights using the filters “From Country + Does not Equal + Ireland" and "To Country + Equals + Ireland".

Check the message volume by clicking the tab "Delivery and Errors" and going to "Outgoing Messages by Top 20 Twilio Numbers".

Comment: Cheers IObert and tks for all the info, I find the Twilio customer service to be top notch and tks for all your help, cheers